# How to setup a react-flowbite modal?

Tags: reactjs, flowbite

While adding the [react-flowbite](https://flowbite-react.com/) modal to a react code, this error appears:

[image: onClick is not defined]

**How to configure all that? How to setup a button so that it toggles the modal onClick?
Thanks**

These are the imports :

```
import {
  Button,
  Checkbox,
  Label,
  Modal,
  TextInput,
} from "flowbite-react";
```

This is the code:
(Couldn't paste it here because the code was more that text)
https://flowbite-react.com/modal

*Scroll down up to "form elements"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use imported Modal as wrapper for your Modal component

```
import { Modal } from "flowbite-react";
function App() {
const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
return (
<button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>toggle modal</button>
<Modal show={show} handleClose={() => setShow(false)}>
<div>Modal Content</div>
</Modal>
)
}
```